# How can design view of a form be disabled by vba code and still display the contents of form correctly?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to disable the design view of my from. Therefore, I saved my database as accde,doing so disables the design mode.However, doesnt load the form correctly.It isn't diplaying the information in drop down boxes as in the accdb file. It is displaying the drop down boxes where I have created a value list and not displaying the data in drop down boxes which have been extracted from a table.

Also, is there any way to hide my tables as well from the users.

Thanks Please assist

Comment: Setup Navigaton Options before compiling to hide the tables. If you're sending a user your accde you'll have to make sure all distributable OCXs and third party items have been installed and distributed to them too. If you don't know how to do that, perhaps it easiest to load the accdb file there first - open the VBE and look for missing references

Answer (score 0):

The VBA code needs to be compiled before saving the file into accde. Also, make sure the trusted location settins is turned on where the database file has been saved.